# Icons not showing after creating custom theme in Magento 2

Tags: php, css, themes, magento2

I made a custom theme that has the magento luma theme as parent, but all icons are not showing on the frontend. A few examples:

searchbar (and cart icon missing)

[image]

Stars missing in rating

[image]

There are a lot of other places missing these icons. I already tried to do a `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` with my store languages but to no avail. In my browser console i dont see any 404 errors in resources, and if i look in my folders i can see the fonts are there.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

as requested a bit of "code", but first the structure is as follows:

```
Vendor
  - MyTheme
    - web
      -css
        -source
          -variables
            ---.less files
          --- .less files
      -images
    -composer.json 
    -registration.php
    -theme.xml
```

contents of my theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
  <title>MyTheme</title>
  <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

**Additional info**

So i did some digging in the html itself. I found that a :before has the icon. When looking at its css its has the following:

```
content: '\e61d';
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

Found in static-m.css

so i tried to edit the content to something else from fontawesome and that works, so that means fontawesome is loaded correctly. So does that mean that the content code does not exists in fontawesome? or does the standard magento icons come from a different library like fontawesome?

Comment: Can you edit the question to share some code for yours, please?

Comment: Any code you want to see in particular?

Comment: Allthat's relevant.  At least that for the two images you posted.

Comment: I edited my question to show you the structure, the rest are just normal less files which are all compiled and loaded if i check the consoletab of my browser. So no real coding actually happened, just a setup with the registration and theme.xml.

Comment: Do you have console errors?

Comment: No, no console errors at all. If i inherit from a existing theme. like in my case luma doesn't it need to automatically use those icons the luma theme uses? (question to everybody)